# API to display block in regions

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I would like to display blocks in region by code, in the same way that I can use context (so: if I'm on a node_view of type "article" display block "user login" on region "Sidebar first", for example).

I know how to load and display blocks but I don't know which is the best place to make it.

Have I to add the render function in regions template?
Or have I to use a theme function to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just assign the block to a region, with visibility settings, in `Admin > Structure > Blocks` ?

Comment: I know this, but I'm searching a way to do this by code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the admin blocks interface, if you really want to manually render blocks, you can render:

Directly in a template:

```
if ($block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta')) {
  print render($block['content']); 
}
```

Via code, with [drupal_add_region_content](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_region_content/7)

```
if ($block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta')) {
  drupal_add_region_content('left',  $block['content']);
}
```